# Xamarin Android: Navigation Click Listener Stop Working On Orientation Change

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I've followed this post https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87795/onoptionsitemselected-not-invoked-using-masterdetails-page-on-android to get my back button event working. It works as expected until I change the orientation of the application. Is there a way to remedy this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per me you just need to stop the changes that happen onConfigurationChange which can be done something like this;

**For API > 13**

```
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation
```

**For API < 13**

```
 ConfigurationChanges =  ConfigChanges.Orientation
```

**For Eg:**

```
[Activity(ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,...)
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

Comment: And what happened? nothing?

Comment: The back button event isn't triggered after changing the orientation.